# font on body two times

Tags: html, css

My font size on my page is suddenly got more bold than it should be. I can see in developer tools, that the font is two times on the body. Is that normal, or could it have something to do with this? When I click the tick away on: 600 14px/1.42857143 Adelle; it looks normal I would say.

What does it mean that the font is two times on the body?
[image: Picture]

Comment: Did you search for this line in your code?

Comment: Somewhere in yaneeda.css it's splitting the body up.  Do you have something like SASS packaging up your css?

Comment: Yes that actually could be ntgCleaner. Would that have something to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two blocks in your CSS file that define the style for the body tag.  This is normal, though not recommended.  In general, you want to combine those two blocks into one.  It's cool how chrome dev tools shows one as strike-through so you know which one the browser is actually using.

Sometimes you really do want two blocks referencing the same html.  Maybe one targets the class name, one the id.  That's not the case here though because chrome dev tools specifically shows that you've styled the `body` tag twice.